# Monitoring - Calculate bandwidth usage of images

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, monitoring, bandwidth

Is there a way to find out the bandwidth usage of a certain mime-type on Windows Server?

Eg. How much GB of images is my server serving each month?

Comment: Parse IIS log files and filter by extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This info is logged within the default-settings of the IIS-Logfiles and can be calculated from there.

You can use the field `cs-uri-stem` to check if it was an picture and if so you could add together the fields `sc-bytes`

Propably the most easy way is to do it by powershell.

[How-to use PowerShell to parse IIS logs file](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/46bc6859-d9e3-47c3-b1a6-5132281df18b/howto-use-powershell-to-parse-iis-logs-files?forum=ITCG)

[Parsing ISS Logs in Powershell](https://bentaylor.work/2016/09/parsing-iis-logs-to-powershell-objects/)